# How to add scrollbars to an open aixterm

Tags: aix

Anyone know how to add scrollbars to a running aixterm? I don't have control of how the aixterm is opened and it doesn't look at my ~/.Xdefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this at your shell prompt:

```
echo "\033[?42"
```

Comment: Also, from your running aixterm, you could spawn a new aixterm using something like this to set whatever options you want:

`aixterm -fn rom11 -bg darkblue -T BLUE -sb -sl 999 -fg white -fullcursor -ls &`

Answer (score 0):

Try  right click.  Should bring up a modes listbox that contains a scrollbar list.